# Can I create javascript for specific woocommerce product categories? Or can I hide items if blank?

Tags: javascript, php, wordpress, woocommerce

Based on *[Display the variations weight on a variable product page in Woocommerce?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52303817/display-the-variations-weight-on-a-variable-product-page-in-woocommerce/52304217#52304217)* answer code, I have implemented some script for Woocommerce so that the product weight is displayed on the product page.

I have also included some script to include metric and imperial weights.

```
add_filter('woocommerce_available_variation', 'display_variation_weight', 10, 3 );
function display_variation_weight( $variation_data, $product, $variation ) {
    $variation_data['price_html'] .= '<span class="weight">'. '  &nbsp;  ('  . $variation_data['weight_html']. '</span>';
    $variation_data['price_html'] .= '<span class="weight">'. ' / ' .round($variation_data['weight_html'] * 2.2)  . ' lbs)' . '</span>';

    return $variation_data;
}
```

However, only one category of products requires this function. I would like to either apply it to a single category or hide it when it is blank. Screenshot below shows the outcomes for the categories without weights.

[image: screenshot here]

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

Please check below code.

```
add_filter('woocommerce_available_variation', 'display_variation_weight', 10, 3 );

function display_variation_weight( $variation_data, $product, $variation ) {

     // Test is the term / category name, You can add the product category in array.
     // If category is assigned to product then if part will be executed.

     if( has_term( array( 'test' ), 'product_cat' ) ) {
         $variation_data['price_html'] .= '<span class="weight">'. '  &nbsp;  ('  . $variation_data['weight_html']. '</span>';
         $variation_data['price_html'] .= '<span class="weight">'. ' / ' .round($variation_data['weight_html'] * 2.2)  . ' lbs)' . '</span>';
     }
     return $variation_data;

}
```

Please let me know if it's working for you or not.
Thanks.

Comment: Hello! Thanks for the reply. Yes I used something similar like the following 
 if ( is_product_category(127) ) {

and it doesn't work either. It doesn't apply at all to the category. For some reason it is being overridden by something else.

Comment: Not sure if it is relevant, but I have also added the following script from somewhere else to move the weight up a few in the product page:

Comment: /*move weight and price to above variant selection*/
function shuffle_variable_product_elements(){
    if ( is_product() ) {
        global $post;
        $product = wc_get_product( $post->ID );
        if ( $product->is_type( 'variable' ) ) {
            remove_action( 'woocommerce_single_variation', 'woocommerce_single_variation', 10 );
            add_action( 'woocommerce_before_variations_form', 'woocommerce_single_variation', 20 );
        }
    }
}
add_action( 'woocommerce_before_single_product', 'shuffle_variable_product_elements' );